# white cursor mode in android studio

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with my cursor mode in android studio. When I copy something ,my cursor mode gets **bigger** than normal and when I click to **insert**,it returns to normal in android studio

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to settings=>plugins=>uncheck the IdeaVim